# Hosting WCF Service in MVC Core (NET 4.6)

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to host my WCF service alongside my MVC Core web app.
In MVC 5 there was an option to add a service route

```
routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("myservice",new ServiceHostFactory(), typeof(MyWCFService)));
```

Is something similar possible in MVC Core ?

Comment: WCF (System.ServiceModel) isn't supported in Core. I don't know that it ever will be. Remain hopeful! :)

Comment: Well my problem is that i currently have a site that has a WCF service in the root e.g www.mysite.com/Service.svc
I will migrate my site to MVC Core but i want to continue hosting the WCF service under same URL. I could simply host service under different url but that would cause huge amount of reconfiguration client side and that the last option i want to take.

Comment: Do you really need Core? Or, can you use the full framework? The ONLY reason core is necessary is if you are doing cross platform work.

Comment: No i don't need Core the project actually targets full framework 4.6.